# I've got to do OR I have to do

Tags: word-difference

Whenever I talk to my friends or teacher , they never use gotta but when I look at natives , they often use gotta after have in the sentence. Can someone please help me with this..

Answer (score 1):

"Have to" and "have got to" are both fine, and mean the same thing.

"Have got to" is informal ("have to" can be formal or informal).

In colloquial speech the "'ve" in "I/you've got to" and the "'s" in "He/she's got to" are often elided, producing "I/you/he/she got to", now sometimes written "I/you/he/she gotta". That last is definitely informal.

Comment: I don't know whether you are British or American, but I'm wondering whether "have got to" is quite as informal in BrE as it is in AmE. That is, "got" is used as the past participle of "get" in BrE, but in AmE, it's usually "gotten."

Comment: I am British, @joiedevivre. Maybe it isn't, but I remember from my childhood that prescriptivist books inveighed against "got" in that construction, You're right that "got" is the ppt in BrE, but that is irrelevant. "I have got it" is different in meaning and construction from "I have got to". it is true that "I have got it" is ambiguous (between "I have it" and "I have acquired it") but that is a different question.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I'm certainly well aware that the meaning in this construction is different, since it is the _only_ expression I say "have got" in. In all other places, I would say "have gotten." Maybe you are right that it is irrelevant, but it certainly gives this expression in English a special flavor for me.

Answer (score 0):

They are interchangeable. The "have got to" expression has a bit more emphasis.

> I have to do my homework.

This doesn't sound too pressing. You have to do it, but maybe not until next week.

> I've got to do my homework.

This could mean that it's due tomorrow! In any case, I'm a bit more stressed about it.

These are very slight connotational distinctions, though. You could say either one in any context.

Comment: I was going to say the form with "got" is more emphatic, but actually I don't think it it. "I **have** to" can be just as emphatic.

Comment: @ColinFine That's why I tried to stress that the connotational difference is **very** slight. You might be right, though, that it's nonexistent. Honestly, it seems like this is a "say whatever you're in the mood to say" kind of difference.